# ajax partial load from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So what I want to do is load only a section of one webpage onto another page.  So I want to grab the content of a page (stuff inbetween a div with a certain id) without the headers and footers.   I know I've seen this before but its, stangly, a hard thing to find.

Anyone kind enough to point me in the right direction?

thank you

Comment: Are these two pages located on the same domain?

Comment: @Sean Kinsey 
no,  but thant won't be a problem, I'm using a php script to load the other page.

Comment: You know that your answer doesn't make sense right? If you use a serverside script to proxy the request, then that script is the page referred to, hence they are on the same domain ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jquery's **[`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** method for that.

```
$('#result').load('test.html #container');
```

This will load contents of element having id `container` from `test.html` page into current page and inside the element with id `result`.

Comment: +1 awsome thanks, exactly what I was looking for.  I guess it was jQuery's docs I saw this before.

Comment: @WalterJ89: You are welcome and yes you are right about jquery docs :)